# JQuery Condition if a class is found or other

Tags: jquery

I have a div which looks like this:

```
<div class="button button-t disabled">
```

Now, the disabled is added at runtime so sometimes it will can the class disabled and sometimes not at all.

Is there anyway on jquery to do this below?

```
example:

IF class button button-t HAS class .disabled then
  //do something
else
 //do something else
```

Comment: When you say "disabled is added at runtime", what do you mean? When is Javascript not run at runtime?

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match your question

Comment: By disabled I just mean a class called disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the answer in your question.

You do it like this:

```
if($('.button.button-t').hasClass('disabled'))
{
  ...
}
```

`hasClass()` returns whether the element has that class or not. It returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: What if there are more than just one element? ***EDIT***: `I have a div` then that's ok ;)